# How to create an optional parser that is able to conditionally drop synthesized items

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I am trying to create an optional parser rule. Depending on the value of the first attribute, I want to optionally emits a data.

Example, for the input:

```
x,2,3
y,3,4
x,5,6
```

If the first character is a `y` then the line should be discarded. Otherwise it will be processed. In this example, if the 3rd attribute is `>= 4` then it is true. The synthesized attribute should be `std::pair<bool, unsigned int>` where the `unsigned int` value is the second attribute.
The parser is:

```
using namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
using Data = std::pair<bool, unsigned>;
BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(Data, make_pair, std::make_pair, 2);

class DataParser :
    public qi::grammar<
    std::string::iterator,
    boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii,
    boost::spirit::ascii::space_type,
    std::vector<Data>()
    >
{
    qi::rule<iterator_type, encoding_type, bool()> type;
    qi::rule<iterator_type, encoding_type, bool()> side;
    // doesn't compile: qi::rule<iterator_type, encoding_type, boost::spirit::ascii::space_type, boost::optional<Data>()> line;
    qi::rule<iterator_type, encoding_type, boost::spirit::ascii::space_type, qi::locals<bool, unsigned, bool>, Data()> line;
    qi::rule<iterator_type, encoding_type, boost::spirit::ascii::space_type, sig_type> start;

public:
    DataParser()
        : base_type(start)
    {
        using namespace qi::labels;

        type = qi::char_[_val = _1 == 'x'];
        side = qi::int_[_val = _1 >= 4];
        line %= (qi::omit[type[_a = _1]] >> ',' >> qi::omit[qi::uint_[_b = _1]] >> ',' >> qi::omit[side[_c = _1]])[if_(_a)[_val = make_pair(_c, _b)]];
        // doesn't compile: line %= (qi::omit[type[_a = _1]] >> ',' >> qi::omit[qi::uint_[_b = _1]] >> ',' >> qi::omit[side[_c = _1]])[if_(_a)[_val = make_pair(_c, _b)].else_[_val = qi::unused]];
        // doesn't compile: line %= (type >> ',' >> qi::uint_ >> ',' >> side)[if_(_1)[_val = make_pair(_3, _2)]];
        // doesn't compile: line %= (type >> ',' >> qi::uint_ >> ',' >> side)[if_(_1)[_val = make_pair(_3, _2)].else_[_val = unused]];
        start = *line;
    }
};
```

I get: `[[false, 2], [false, 0], [true, 5]]` where I want to get: `[[false, 2], [true, 5]]` (the second entry should be discarded).

I tried with `boost::optional<Data>` for the `data` rule and also to assign `unused` to `_val` but nothing worked.

### Edit after fixing the issue with the accepted answer

The new rules are now:

```
using Data = std::pair<bool, unsigned>;
BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(Data, make_pair, std::make_pair, 2);

class DataParser :
    public qi::grammar<
        std::string::iterator,
        boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii,
        boost::spirit::ascii::blank_type,
        std::vector<Data>()
    >
{
    using Items = boost::fusion::vector<bool, unsigned, bool>;

    qi::rule<iterator_type, encoding_type, bool()> type;
    qi::rule<iterator_type, encoding_type, bool()> side;
    qi::rule<iterator_type, encoding_type, boost::spirit::ascii::blank_type, Items()> line;
    qi::rule<iterator_type, encoding_type, boost::spirit::ascii::blank_type, sig_type> start;

public:
    DataParser()
        : base_type(start)
    {
        using namespace qi::labels;
        namespace px = boost::phoenix;

        type = qi::char_[_val = _1 == 'x'];
        side = qi::int_[_val = _1 >= 4];
        line = type >> ',' >> qi::uint_ >> ',' >> side;
        start = line[if_(_1)[px::push_back(_val, make_pair(_3, _2))]] % qi::eol;
    }
};
```

The key points being to use the semantic action to decide if the synthesized attribute should be added by using all attributes of the previous rule, in this case `line`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. You use lots of power-tools. But remember, [with great power comes...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/With_great_power_comes_great_responsibility).

In particular, qi::locals, phoenix, semantic actions: they're all complicating life so only use them as a last resort (or when they're a natural fit, which is rarely¹).

Think directly,

```
 start = *line;

 line = // ....
```

When you say

> If the first character is a y then the line should be discarded. Otherwise it will be processed.

You can express this *directly*:

```
 line = !qi::lit('y') >> // ...
```

Alternatively, spell out what starters to accept:

```
 line = qi::omit[ qi::char_("xz") ] >> // ...
```

Done.

### Straight Forward Mapping

Here I'll cheat by re-ordering the `pair<unsigned, bool>` so it matches the input order. Now everything works out of the box without "any" magic:

```
line   = !qi::lit('y') >> qi::omit[qi::alnum] >> ',' >> qi::int_ >> ',' >> side;
ignore = +(qi::char_ - qi::eol);

start = qi::skip(qi::blank) [ (line | ignore) % qi::eol ];
```

However it WILL result in the spurious entries as you noticed: **[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/66jd7Y)**

```
Parsed: {(2, false), (0, false), (5, true)}
```

### Improving

Now you could go hack around things by changing the `eol` to also eat subsequent lines that don't appear to contain valid data lines. However, it becomes unwieldy, and we still have the desire to flip the pair's members.

So, here's where I think an actrion **could** be handy:

```
  public:
    DataParser() : DataParser::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi::labels;

        start  = qi::skip(qi::blank) [
              (qi::char_ >> ',' >> qi::uint_ >> ',' >> qi::int_) [
                  _pass = process(_val, _1, _2, _3) ]
            % qi::eol ];
    }

  private:
    struct process_f {
        template <typename... T>
        bool operator()(Datas& into, char id, unsigned type, int side) const {
            switch(id) {
                case 'z': case 'x':
                    into.emplace_back(side >= 4, type);
                    break;
                case 'y': // ignore
                    break;
                case 'a':
                    return false; // fail the rule
            }
            return true;
        }
    };

    boost::phoenix::function<action_f> process;
```

You can see, there's a nice separation of concerns now. You parse `(char,int,int)` and conditionally process it. That's what's keeping this relatively simple compared to your attempts.

### Live Demo

[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/bccWqW)

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

using Data = std::pair<bool, unsigned>;
using Datas = std::vector<Data>;

template <typename It>
class DataParser : public qi::grammar<It, Datas()> {
    using Skipper = qi::blank_type;
    qi::rule<It, Datas(), Skipper> line;
    qi::rule<It, Datas()> start;

  public:
    DataParser() : DataParser::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi::labels;

        start  = qi::skip(qi::blank) [
              (qi::char_ >> ',' >> qi::uint_ >> ',' >> qi::int_) [
                  _pass = process(_val, _1, _2, _3) ]
            % qi::eol ];
    }

  private:
    struct process_f {
        template <typename... T>
        bool operator()(Datas& into, char id, unsigned type, int side) const {
            switch(id) {
                case 'z': case 'x':
                    into.emplace_back(side >= 4, type);
                    break;
                case 'y': // ignore
                    break;
                case 'a':
                    return false; // fail the rule
            }
            return true;
        }
    };

    boost::phoenix::function<process_f> process;
};

int main() {
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    DataParser<It> p;

    for (std::string const input : {
            "x,2,3\ny,3,4\nx,5,6", 
            })
    {
        auto f = begin(input), l = end(input);
        Datas d;
        auto ok = qi::parse(f, l, p, d);

        if (ok) {
            fmt::print("Parsed: {}\n", d);
        } else {
            fmt::print("Parsed failed\n", d);
        }

        if (f!=l) {
            fmt::print("Remaining unparsed: '{}'\n", std::string(f,l));
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Parsed: {(false, 2), (true, 5)}
```

---

¹ [Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I still need clarification if you don't mind. It seems that you successfully skip the entry by having `_pass` set to `false`. When I try it, the parsing stop completely and it only returns the first entry. How, in your code, is the parser able to continue parsing the rest of the input?

Comment: I do not. `_pass` is actually never used here (or always true). I just included it in case you have other applications where you want to actively _fail_ the parse (e.g. if you [add input starting with `'a'`](https://godbolt.org/z/6srvaj)).

Comment: Alternatively just [ignore the whole `_pass` thing](https://godbolt.org/z/4T4Wfq)

Comment: Obviously! I see now that that you achieve the discarding by NOT having the vector `Datas` modified. So no way to implicitly having an entry discarded. Thanks.